# Pass class created by class.forName as an argument

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have class "Q1" that extends Fragment. I create it using class.forName and then I need to pass it as an argument to method that receives (int,Fragment), but there is Wrong second type error. i cannot just cast object to "Q1", because 
I'm going to create more classes like "Q2,Q3" and etc. So is it possible to pass unknown class to this method

```
Object clazz = Class.forName(fClass).newInstance(); //fClass is the class name
fTrans.replace(FragmentPlace, clazz);// Wrong second type
```

P.S This would work perfectly if I use object created not by class.forName.
Like this

```
Q1 clazz = new Q1();
 fTrans.replace(FragmentPlace, clazz);
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try casting second argument to `Fragment`? Because in your example you pass `Object` as second argument:

```
fTrans.replace(FragmentPlace, (Fragment) clazz);
```